# Debbugging angularjs app without ripple or browser because it uses cordovasqlite plugin

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, cordova, debugging

In my AngularJS/Ionic app I use the cordova-sqlite plugin and a local database to store data; I also use a web service to fill the database with data from a remote database. Well, sometimes I get a strange behaviour when I try to get data from the remote database.

My problem is that I can't debug the code in the way it is now.

If I try to use the ripple emulator it says that it can't work with the sqlite plugin. I googled around and found out that any plugin which uses native code won't work with ripple. I wanted to see the network transferring operations on ripple.

At the time Im writing this I'm usually debugging opening the system console and checking them out but this isn't a really good way to debug. I work on a mac with WebStorm.

Is there a way to debug my code on mac live on the device or simulator like in visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried GapDebug? It let's you debug your Cordova/Phonegap app on an Android or iOS device via Chrome Dev Tools or Safari Webkit Inspector and is almost magical. -> https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug/

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for. Thank you sooo much this saves me so much time.